# Date range using jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, date, datepicker

I'm using [this link](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range) to chose date.

Over here there are 2 different input fields to select the start date and end date.

I rather want something [like this](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#multiple-calendars) which will have only 1 input field but will have the ability to select 2 different dates, which will serve my start date and end date.

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

try it like this:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  numberOfMonths: 2,
  showButtonPanel: true
});
```

Comment: I guess you misinterpreted my question. I want to select 2 different dates from 1 datepicker.

Comment: As in right now I'm able to select only 1 date per datepicker, but I rather want to select 2 dates instead.

Comment: do I need to include another library for that? `TypeError: $(...).multiDatesPicker is not a function maxPicks: 2`

Comment: Its CDN version is available?

Answer (score 0):

*Default jQuery UI datepicker **does not** support multiple dates*, but here is a version [**kelvin's multi-date select**](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerMultiple.html) which can be customized.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use **MultiDatesPicker v1.6.1 for jQuery UI**

here is the [link](http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/)

`example`

```
$('#maxPicks').multiDatesPicker({
    maxPicks: 2
});
```

Comment: do I need to include another library for that? `TypeError: $(...).multiDatesPicker is not a function
 

maxPicks: 2`

Comment: Its CDN version is available?

Comment: I couldn't see its CDN version. All I can see is download option.

Comment: @user1162512 I dont think a CDN is available , though `github` raw js is available here https://raw.github.com/dubrox/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/master/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js but it showing `unable to excute script , some mime type error...`